# how to loging all WebSocket response in one page using chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I visited a web page, and find some of its chart data using websocket to return. Becauses the page doesn't provide export chart data function. So I wish to develop a chrome extension to do this.
My first step is to handle all websocket reponse data in Extension. How can I do that? Thanks~ 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Devtools already exports WebSocket traffic: right click on any request in the network log of the network panel and click "Save all as HAR with content".

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks, But Not everyone is a programmer.